# Coq can't find subterm when using rewrite tactic

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I'm trying to do a modified proof of `compile_correct` from the [first chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/StackMachine.html) of Certified Programming with Dependent Types.  In my version, I try to make use of the fact that `progDenote` is a fold, and use a weaker inductive hypothesis in the proof of the main lemma in priving `compile_correct`.

The code that is identical with the book is:

```
Require Import Bool Arith List.
Set Implicit Arguments.

Inductive binop : Set := Plus | Times.

Inductive exp : Set :=
  | Const : nat -> exp
  | Binop : binop -> exp -> exp -> exp.

Definition binopDenote (b : binop) : nat -> nat -> nat :=
  match b with
    | Plus => plus
    | Times => mult
  end.

Fixpoint expDenote (e : exp) : nat :=
  match e with
    | Const n => n
    | Binop b e1 e2 => (binopDenote b) (expDenote e1) (expDenote e2)
  end.

Inductive instr : Set :=
  | iConst : nat -> instr
  | iBinop : binop -> instr.

Definition prog := list instr.
Definition stack := list nat.

Definition instrDenote (i : instr) (s : stack) : option stack :=
  match i with
    | iConst n => Some (n :: s)
    | iBinop b =>
      match s with
        | arg1 :: arg2 :: s' => Some ((binopDenote b) arg1 arg2 :: s')
        | _ => None
      end
  end.

Fixpoint compile (e : exp) : prog :=
  match e with
    | Const n => iConst n :: nil
    | Binop b e1 e2 => compile e2 ++ compile e1 ++ iBinop b :: nil
  end.
```

Then I define my own version of `prog_denote` which is a fold over the list of instructions in a program:

```
Definition bind {A B : Type} (a : option A) (f : A -> option B) : option B :=
  match a with
    | Some x => f x
    | None => None
  end.

Definition instrDenote' (s : option stack) (i : instr) : option stack :=
  bind s (instrDenote i).

Definition progDenote (p : prog) (s : stack) : option stack :=
  fold_left instrDenote' p (Some s).
```

I then try to prove a weaker version of `compile_correct` from the book:

```
Lemma compile_correct' : forall e s,
  progDenote (compile e) s = Some (expDenote e :: s).
induction e.
intro s.
unfold compile.
unfold expDenote.
unfold progDenote at 1.
simpl.
reflexivity.
intro s.
unfold compile.
fold compile.
unfold expDenote.
fold expDenote.
unfold progDenote.
rewrite fold_left_app.
rewrite fold_left_app.
unfold progDenote in IHe2.
rewrite (IHe2 s).
unfold progDenote in IHe1.
rewrite (IHe1 (expDenote e2 :: s)).
```

My proof breaks at the last line, with the proof state

```
1 subgoal
b : binop
e1 : exp
e2 : exp
IHe1 : forall s : stack,
       fold_left instrDenote' (compile e1) (Some s) =
       Some (expDenote e1 :: s)
IHe2 : forall s : stack,
       fold_left instrDenote' (compile e2) (Some s) =
       Some (expDenote e2 :: s)
s : stack
______________________________________(1/1)
fold_left instrDenote' (iBinop b :: nil)
  (fold_left instrDenote' (compile e1) (Some (expDenote e2 :: s))) =
Some (binopDenote b (expDenote e1) (expDenote e2) :: s)
```

And the error is

```
Error:
Found no subterm matching "fold_left instrDenote' (compile e1)
                             (Some (expDenote e2 :: s))" in the current goal.
```

At this stage in the proof, I am doing induction on `e`, the expression being compiled, and dealing with the `Binop` constructor of `exp`.  I don't understand why I am getting this error, because once I apply `IHe1` to `expDenote e2 :: s` there are no bound variables.  This seems to be the usual problem with applying rewrite rules doesn't work.  I also checked that the term I'm trying to create:

```
fold_left instrDenote' (iBinop b :: nil)
  (Some (expDenote e1 :: expDenote e2 :: s)) =
Some (binopDenote b (expDenote e1) (expDenote e2) :: s)
```

type checks.

What else can go wrong with a rewrite rule, when the subexpression it's complaining about is clearly there in the goal?

EDIT: As suggested, I changed the display settings in coqide to the equivalent of Set Printing All.  This revealed the problem to be that the definition of `stack` had been unfolded to `list nat` at one place in the goal, which prevented the subterm from being recognized.  The goal printed with the new settings was

```
1 subgoal
b : binop
e1 : exp
e2 : exp
IHe1 : forall s : stack,
       @eq (option stack)
         (@fold_left (option stack) instr instrDenote' (compile e1)
            (@Some stack s)) (@Some (list nat) (@cons nat (expDenote e1) s))
IHe2 : forall s : stack,
       @eq (option stack)
         (@fold_left (option stack) instr instrDenote' (compile e2)
            (@Some stack s)) (@Some (list nat) (@cons nat (expDenote e2) s))
s : stack
______________________________________(1/1)
@eq (option stack)
  (@fold_left (option stack) instr instrDenote'
     (@cons instr (iBinop b) (@nil instr))
     (@fold_left (option stack) instr instrDenote' (compile e1)
        (@Some (list nat) (@cons nat (expDenote e2) s))))
  (@Some (list nat)
     (@cons nat (binopDenote b (expDenote e1) (expDenote e2)) s))
```

And the error was

```
Error:
Found no subterm matching "@fold_left (option stack) instr instrDenote'
                             (compile e1)
                             (@Some stack (@cons nat (expDenote e2) s))" in the current goal.
```

Comment: Could you add what gets printed if you enable `Set Printing All.`? (Just add this line before your proof).

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.  Now I see that the expressions are different, as `stack` appears as `list nat` in the goal.  I don't know enough about Coq to understand why the definition of `stack` has been expanded like this in the goal (and why it's still displayed as `stack` with default Printing settings).

Comment: Now that I see what happened, `fold stack` fixes the issue.  From what I've read, the `unfold` tactic is not completely obvious for a beginner in how deep it unfolds an expression, so that combined with the default display settings seems to be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though with default display settings, the subterm seems to appear in the goal, with `Set Printing All` enabled, it becomes clear that the subterm does not match the goal because in the goal, `stack` has been unfolded to `list nat`.  So `fold stack` is needed to turn `list nat` back into `stack` in the goal.

It seems like as a beginner I was tripped up by the combination of the following:

- The `unfold` tactic unfolds more definitions than a beginner would expect.
- The default display settings (in CoqIDE in my case) can hide this because they fold some terms.

Thanks to Arthur Azevedo De Amorim for suggesting enabling `Set Printing All`.